# Zooming image smaller than UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I want to have a larger frame than an image so i do something like this:
[image]

And of course i have `UIScrollViewDelegate` and i handle the zooming. But there is one problem. When i zoom picture i can scroll to this "blue" empty space in a zoom mode.

After zoom when my zoom picture width is greater than scrollView width i wish that user cannot scroll to this empty space. How can i achieve that?

(1) zoomScale 1.0:

[image]

(2) after zoom and move to edge:

[image]

(3) what i want it to be:

[image]

**EDIT:**
After setting contentInset:

```
[self.scView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -30, 0, -(self.frame.size.width-csc.width/2))];
```

Why it is moving to left?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There might be a simpler approach, but one way that works is to use a negative contentInset (UIEdgeInsets) to the scrollView.

Comment: I set it: `[self.scView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -100, 0, -100)];` for `image.size.width = 120`, so it should be 320 full screen App, but it is not working.

Comment: Thats odd.. when i try to do this only on one side (`    [self.scView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -(self.frame.size.width-csc.width/2))];` it works only for this one side. But when i try it on second parameters it moved image (screen in Q).